# Ways to increase Elasticsearch indexing speed?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm setting up a one node ES to handle udp messages from a network and I'm using logstash to pipeline the messages.

input -> udp
no filter
output -> Elasticsearch (single worker, flush size is 5000)

For all the tests I ran, 25k is the max number of events/sec before significant packet loss. I know the bottleneck is not the udp input or network because when I use stdout or file output instead of ES, the throughput can be as high as  80k/s.

The node is 16G/12T (RAID 0) but the disk is HDD.
I've tried different settings but can't get past 25k evts/s. I wonder if I'm just hitting the hardware limitations and the only way is to use SSD. 
Anyone have been in the same situation? Any tricks to allow ES to index at a speed close to stdout? Here is what I've tried so far (sending 1M udp pkts in 40s, that's roughly 25K/s):

1. increased udp worker to 8  --> realized that input wasn't the problem
2. increase ES output workers to 2, 4, 8 --> **worse** throughput, 90% loss with 8 workers. think HDD doesn't do well with concurrent I/O.
3. increased refresh_interval from 1s to 30s --> *slight* improvement
4. number of shards 1, 2, 5, 10 --> no obvious improvement

Here is what I added in elasticsearch.yml

```
script.disable_dynamic: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.enabled: true
action.auto_create_index: false
bootstrap.mlockall: true
action.disable_delete_all_indices: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries:15
indices.recovery.concurrent_streams: 4
index.routing.allocation.disable_allocation: false
index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1
index.store.type: mmapfs
index.refresh_interval: 60000
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 30000
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
index.translog.flush_threshold_ops: 50000
```

Comment: What version of logstash are you using? Are you using the bulk api?

Comment: @JoshC. logstash 1.5.3 and I have `flush_size => 5000` in my elasticsearch output, I assume that tells it to use bulk?

Comment: How much memory have you allocated to Elasticsearch?  Have you increased the ulimit settings?

Comment: @AlainCollins I gave ES 12G: `ES_HEAP_SIZE=12g MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited  MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144` should I try increasing map count?

Comment: Those settings look fine, though more memory is always good.  Did you raise ulimit for open files?

Comment: @AlainCollins thanks for following up, I had `max_file_descriptors : 65535` , and raised it 3x, it didn't seem to increase the performance, maybe it wasn't even using 65k?

Comment: You covered the basic system parameters.  Tom's suggestions for more ES tuning and a larger cluster are good next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I expirienced the the best way will be to switch the disks to SSD, it will really improve your performance. Another might be to move from a single elasticsearch server to multiple servers in a cluster.

From your question I see that you already tried some less obviouse solutions like increasing number of workers and the indices.memory.index_buffer_size parameter, so these tricks seem to hit the hardware limitation.

I would suggest using the "sar" or "iotop" tools to verify if the limitation is really in the disks, if you see 100% utilization of the disks then there is no configuration way to fix it unless you make elasticsearch write data more efficiently to the disks.

Comment: ES was writing at merely 20-30M/s according to iotop. I benchmarked the disk IO, it's able to do 1.2G/s at 100% utilization, then I did a database io benchmarking, which is more random RW and the peak value is only around 25M/s. Looks like SSD+a perc that allows caching is the way to go. Thanks!